# Is it good practice to put static methods in Laravel models?

Tags: php, laravel, static

I am new to Laravel and MVC development in general.

I have method that imports data from a CSV file. Every line represents a user, and a document related to the user.

The import function checks if the User exists (based on a login field in the CSV) and if not creates a new user. It then creates a new UserDocument for that user.

I have a createIfNotExists() method in my User model:

```
public static function createIfNotExists($username, $password)
{
    $userId= DB::table('users')->where('login', $username)->pluck('id');

    if(is_null($userId))
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setHasher(new Cartalyst\Sentry\Hashing\NativeHasher);
        $user->login = $username;
        $user->email = $username;
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->save();

        return $user;

    }

    return User::find($userId);
}
```

I call that method in the csv import method like this:

```
$user= User::createIfNotExists($userLogin, $userPassword);
```

**Two questions:**

- Is it good practice to have the createIfNotExists() method in the User model? Or should it be somewhere else?
- Is it good practice that it is a static method?

Comment: If you look at the Eloquent Model class there are plenty of static methods like [`Model::find`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L640) for example. So I wouldn't worry about it too much

Comment: If it makes sense to have a static method, then have a static method. If it makes no sense, then don't have it. There is no criteria that can be used to figure out whether static is bad or good practice. It depends on what you need to do and how static/non-static helps you to do it.

Comment: There was an article I read about unit testable code which advocated not using `static` anything or `new` anything anywhere in your **units**. Meaning that your **units** get tested and they need to have all dependencies injected into them (so you can inject mocked dependencies, instead of real dependencies). The only places where any `global` behavior (such as `statics`) can occur is in the application "frame", meaning the part which isn't modular it's used to load modules.

Comment: that's a question for https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ as SO is about solving practical code issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the `firstOrCreate()` method from Eloquent to achieve what you're doing in your sample code.

It is fine to include static methods in your models, especially as convenience methods, but try use them sparingly and don't let your models get too fat (it can be hard to test static methods).